# .NET export to excel - child rows not displayed

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, excel

In my asp.net application, I let the user export some data from the view on a button click. The code bellow exports an excel file. The problem is that I can't figure it out how to display the models list of objects.

```
        var grid = new GridView();
        grid.DataSource = exportModels;
        grid.DataBind();

        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Exported_Orders.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        grid.RenderControl(htw);

        Response.Write(sw.ToString());

        Response.End();
```

The data-source model is this:

```
public class ExportOrdersViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CustomerFirstName { get; set; }
        public string CustomerLastName { get; set; }
        public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }
        public string CustomerMobile { get; set; }
        public string ShippingStreet { get; set; }
        public string ShippingCity { get; set; }
        public string ShippingCountry { get; set; }
        public string ShippingPostalCode { get; set; }
        public string ShippingTo { get; set; }
        public bool IsShipped { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ExportOrdersItemViewModel> Items { get; set; }

    }

    public class ExportOrdersItemViewModel
    {
        public string TicketName { get; set; }
        public string EventName { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public string CurrencyId { get; set; }
        public string PaymentCurrencyId { get; set; }
        public string UnitPrice { get; set; }
        public string PaymentUnitPrice { get; set; }
    }
```

The ExportOrderViewModel contains a list of ExportOrderItemViewModel and when the file is exported, the item rows of each order are missing form that file. I really need some help on how to add those fields when exporting.

Here is the caption with the exported file:

[image]

This is what the grid object contains right before the excel file is created:
[image]

Comment: Does your GridView show these Items? As soon as you exceed all but the simplest type of export I would suggest you generate a real excel file with a library designed for it.

Comment: In the debug mode, the grids data-source property contains 2 elements and each of those elements contains 3 items

Comment: You are grabbing the HTML that represents the grid and asking Excel to render it, so you are not going to get anything that is not shown in the grid even if the underlying data is correct. I'm not sure how all of this would behave since you have a hierarchy of data, but again, you should consider generating a real Excel file. It is not that difficult, I like the ClosedXML library but there others that are free and do not require Excel installed on the server.

Comment: Can you provide me a link on how to do this exactly?

Comment: Did not read really read it, but [try this](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml/wiki/Deliver-an-Excel-file-in-ASP.NET). Remember, you will be operating on the datasource of the grid, not the grid itself.

Comment: Even with CloseXML library I didn't manage to display the list property inside the .xlsx document. I even created a custom DataTable that contains a row that reffers another DataTable(for the list of items) and when the document is created, the Items row is empty :(  Maybe someone can help me with a solution for this

Comment: Sounds like that might be appropriate for a separate question. I think you have a high likelihood of someone helping if you show your code that generates the file and explain what is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Crowcoder suggested, I used the CLoseXML library and finally succeeded to find a solution for my problem.

This is the code that generates the Excel that I wanted

```
using (var workBook = new XLWorkbook())
            {
                var workSheet = workBook.Worksheets.Add("Guests");

                var guestTable = new DataTable();
                guestTable.Columns.Add(Resources.Strings.FirstName, typeof(string));
                guestTable.Columns.Add(Resources.Strings.LastName, typeof(string));
                guestTable.Columns.Add(Resources.Strings.TicketName, typeof(string));
                guestTable.Columns.Add(Resources.Strings.TicketType, typeof(string));
                guestTable.Columns.Add(Resources.Strings.ShortCode, typeof(string));
                guestTable.Columns.Add(Resources.Strings.HasVisitorEnteredEvent, typeof(string));
                foreach (var entry in guestList)
                {
                    guestTable.Rows.Add(
                        entry.FirstName,
                        entry.LastName,
                        entry.TicketName,
                        entry.TicketType,
                        entry.ShortCode,
                        entry.HasEntered);
                }
                workSheet.Cell(1, 1).InsertTable(guestTable);
                workSheet.Tables.ForEach(t => t.ShowAutoFilter = false);
                workSheet.Style.Alignment.Vertical = XLAlignmentVerticalValues.Center;
                workSheet.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
                workSheet.Tables.ForEach(t => t.Theme = XLTableTheme.TableStyleLight13);
                workSheet.Columns().AdjustToContents();
                workBook.SaveAs(outputStream);
            }
```